# How can I get more then one row with "AND" query in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
id - idProduct - idFilter
65 -    494    -    3
66 -    495    -    3
67 -    497    -    17
68 -    500    -    17
69 -    500    -    3
```

How I can get all idProducts who have idFilter 17 AND 3. In this case this is only product with id - 500

I try something like this:
$query="SELECT idProduct FROM tablename WHERE (idFilter = '3') OR (idFilter = '17') GROUP BY idProduct";

I know it's stupid but I don't know any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Where is your code you tried? And it is unclear wht you are trying to make. .. Explain it more

Comment: Can you try this `SELECT distinct(idProduct),count(*) as total FROM  tablename WHERE idFilter IN (17,3) GROUP BY idProduct  having total = 2;`

Comment: Thank you @Ajith it looks nice. I get what I want. Thank you one more time.

Comment: @MilosPopovic Welcome :) I ll post my answer so that someone can use the same

Comment: @MilosPopovic Please accept the answer if it does helps you

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need to compare multiple row values on a single column, Such that the value should satisfy with an ANS condition.

Then you can do the following trick to achieve that:

```
SELECT distinct(idProduct) as idProduct,count(*) AS total FROM  tablename 
        WHERE idFilter IN (17,3) GROUP BY idProduct  
        HAVING total = 2; 
        //Having will force result to have both 17 and 3  else 17 or 3 alone will be in the result
```

If using php variable for the above ids, you can try the following

```
$inArray = array(17,3);
$sql = "SELECT distinct(idProduct) as idProduct,count(*) AS total FROM  tablename 
        WHERE idFilter IN (".implode(',',$inArray).") GROUP BY idProduct  
        HAVING total = '".count($inArray)."'";
```